Spring-AI : How to connect Redis VectorStore?
According to this commit, I now need to connect using RedisAutoConfiguration instead of RedisVectorStoreAutoConfiguration and I'm curious about how.
commit comment
Here is the Redis connection information.
spring:
  ai:
    openai:
      api-key: ${OPENAI_API_KEY}
  data:
    redis:
      host: ${REDIS_HOST}
      port: ${REDIS_PORT}
      password: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
  profiles:
    include: SECRET-KEYS

I've tried many things, but I get the following exceptions:
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:105) ~[jedis-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:162) ~[jedis-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:221) ~[jedis-5.0.2.jar:na]
...

After checking it many times, the host, port, and password were written the same, but only the same result is repeated. The above exception continues after changing the Spring AI version from 1.0.0-M1 to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

for connecting to redis you have to embed the user id and password in the uri
*spring:
  ai:
    vectorstore:
      redis:
        uri: redis://:XXXXXXXXXXX@redis-19438.c330.asia-south1-1.gce.redns.redis-*

I did this using redis cloud. I simply had to copy the password from redis cloud and use it in the URI.
You can refer this code as well
